# How to search string in NSArray of NSObject Swift 3.0?

Tags: ios, swift3, nsarray

I am working on UiSearchbar,where if an user type some string, i have to show him the related suggestions. Right now the array is containing data in format like below:

```
"Name: Optional(\"2.1 - Classroom\")",
"Name: Optional(\"2.11 - Classroom\")",
"Name: Optional(\"2.22 - Classroom\")",
"Name: Optional(\"2.13 - Classroom\")",
"Name: Optional(\"2.34 - Classroom\")",
"Name: Optional(\"2.55 - Classroom\")"
```

What I want to do is, when an user type 2.1 then i want to suggest him all the names start with `2.1` . I have tried all the suggestions i got from internet. However, i am new to iOS so i can't figure out that how i can do this.
This is my code :

```
func searchBar(_ searchBar: UISearchBar, textDidChange searchText: String){
    if searchText.characters.count == 0{
        isSearch = false;
        self.resulttableview.reloadData()
    }else{
        let filtered  = list.filter(){
            return ($0 as AnyObject).contains(searchText) // 2.1 or searchtext
        }
        print(filtered)
    }
}
```

For assigning the array

```
func itemsDownloaded(items: NSArray){
    list = items
    self.resulttableview.reloadData()
}
```

And this code is for retrieving data from JSON and store in mutable array :

```
func downloadItems(){
    let url = NSURL(string: urlPath)!

    var session: URLSession!
    let configuration = URLSessionConfiguration.default

    session = URLSession(configuration: configuration, delegate: self, delegateQueue: nil)
    let task = session.dataTask(with: url as URL)

    task.resume()
}

func urlSession(_ session: URLSession, dataTask: URLSessionDataTask, didReceive data: Data){
    self.data.append(data);
}

func urlSession(_ session: URLSession, task: URLSessionTask, didCompleteWithError error: Error?){
    if error != nil{
        print("Failed to download data")
    }else{
        print("Data downloaded")
        self.parseJSON()
    }
}

func parseJSON(){
    var jsonResult: NSMutableArray = NSMutableArray()

    do{
        let jsonResults = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: self.data as Data , options: JSONSerialization.ReadingOptions.allowFragments) as! NSArray
        jsonResult = jsonResults.mutableCopy() as! NSMutableArray
    }catch let error as NSError{
        print(error)
    }

    var jsonElement = NSDictionary()
    let locations: NSMutableArray = NSMutableArray()

    for i in 0 ..< jsonResult.count{
        jsonElement = jsonResult[i] as! NSDictionary
        let location = roommodel()

        if let name = jsonElement["name"] as? String{
            location.name = name
        }

        locations.add(location)
    }

    DispatchQueue.main.async{
        self.delegate.itemsDownloaded(items: locations)
    }

}
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: have you tried using filter function?

Comment: Filter function? Do you mean using {$0...}?

Comment: yes. do type cast and apply filter.

Comment: I tried that one but I am getting error. `let result = list.filter({($0 as AnyObject).name == searchText})print(result)`  this is my code for filtering but it's returning me null

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, *don't use* `NSArray` and `NSMutableArray` in Swift code.

For example, `location` should be declared as:

```
var locations: [roommodel] = []
```

and list as

```
var list: [roommodel] = []
```

(and you should name classes with camelcase `RoomModel`).

Then the filtering can be simplified to:

```
let filtered = list.filter {
    return ($0.name ?? "").hasPrefix(searchText)
}
```

or, for "contains" search:

```
let filtered = list.filter {
    return ($0.name ?? "").range(of: searchText) != nil
}
```

with more complex options:

```
let filtered = list.filter {
    return ($0.name ?? "").range(of: searchText, options: [.caseInsensitive, .diacriticsInsensitive]) != nil
}
```

Comment: Ok let me try first

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
let filtered  = list.filter(){

        return ($0 as AnyObject).contains("2.1") // 2.1 or searchtext

        }
        print(filtered)
```

Comment: I tried this but i am getting this error `libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException`

Comment: please add the function which returning array list to your question

Comment: i want to look for function which is returning the list of data for filtering.

Comment: can you add name property to this line return ($0 as AnyObject).contains("2.1")

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/139672/discussion-between-mohammad-julfikar-and-adarshau).